# 2 columns with background image filling 100% of the screen

Tags: css, background-image, multiple-columns

I'm a beginner in CSS and I want to create a landing page with 2 columns (left and right) with each column a different background image.

width: 2 images should fill 50% of the screen.
height: 100% of the screen.

I thought it would be simple but cannot figure it out. Can someone give me some advise please.

thanks...

Comment: Can you post a snippet with relevant code you write?

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `position:absolute;`, with a background-image:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="half-page left"></div>
<div class="half-page right"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.half-page {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:50%;
    background-size:cover;
}
.left {
    left:0;
    background-image:url(www.url.com/image.png);
}
.right {
    right:0;
    background-image:url(www.url.com/image2.png);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**CSS**

```
.wrap {
    width: 100%;
    overflow:auto;
}

.fleft {
    float:left; 
    width: 50%;
    background:url("http://res2.windows.microsoft.com/resbox/en/windows/main/01fdadc8-e0e2-46a2-aac8-50b174f40cca_4.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    height: 100%;
}



.fright {
    float: right;
    background:url("http://wallpapers55.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/Best-Beach-Wallpapers-Background-HD-Wallpaper.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="fleft">Hello World This is LEFT Content</div>
    <div class="fright"> Hello World This is RIGHT Content</div>
</div>
```